# Difference between binomial, binomial() and 'binomial'

Tags: r

What is the difference between binomial, binomial() and 'binomial' when using glm. They are not identical, as can be see by following code:

```
> library(MASS)
> bwdf = birthwt[-10]    
> mod = glm(low~., data=bwdf, family=binomial)
> mod2 = glm(low~., data=bwdf, family=binomial())
> mod3 = glm(low~., data=bwdf, family="binomial")
> identical(mod, mod2)
[1] FALSE
> identical(mod3, mod2)
[1] FALSE
> identical(mod3, mod)
[1] FALSE
```

But the values are identical:

```
> mod

Call:  glm(formula = low ~ ., family = binomial, data = bwdf)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          age          lwt        race2        race3       smoke1          ptl          ht1          ui1          ftv  
    0.48062     -0.02955     -0.01542      1.27226      0.88050      0.93885      0.54334      1.86330      0.76765      0.06530  

Degrees of Freedom: 188 Total (i.e. Null);  179 Residual
Null Deviance:      234.7 
Residual Deviance: 201.3        AIC: 221.3
> 
> mod2

Call:  glm(formula = low ~ ., family = binomial(), data = bwdf)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          age          lwt        race2        race3       smoke1          ptl          ht1          ui1          ftv  
    0.48062     -0.02955     -0.01542      1.27226      0.88050      0.93885      0.54334      1.86330      0.76765      0.06530  

Degrees of Freedom: 188 Total (i.e. Null);  179 Residual
Null Deviance:      234.7 
Residual Deviance: 201.3        AIC: 221.3
> 
> mod3

Call:  glm(formula = low ~ ., family = "binomial", data = bwdf)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          age          lwt        race2        race3       smoke1          ptl          ht1          ui1          ftv  
    0.48062     -0.02955     -0.01542      1.27226      0.88050      0.93885      0.54334      1.86330      0.76765      0.06530  

Degrees of Freedom: 188 Total (i.e. Null);  179 Residual
Null Deviance:      234.7 
Residual Deviance: 201.3        AIC: 221.3
```

Is there any difference?

Comment: Why not inspect the structures? Each one will contain a copy (as a string) of the command that invoked it, so for that reason alone the three objects cannot ever be identical.

Comment: They have different call elements, and that's why `identical()` returns false.  `all.equal(mod, mod2)` is more informative. They still use the same family in the end, which you can see with `mod$family$family`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that the `identical` function is very picky and that part of your `mod` objects is the call that was used to create the object.  That `call` piece will differ based on the parentheses and quotes and so `identical` will say that they differ.  Try calling `identical` on the pieces of the mod objects that you care about and see if they are identical.

If you look at the first few lines of the code of `glm` you will see that it checks the `family` argument and if it is a character string, then it uses `get` to "get" the function of that name.  If `family` is a function (either passed in, or as a result of `get`) then it calls the function.  So whether you pass in the name as a character string, the function, or the results of evaluating the function, after the 1st part of the code you will have the exact same thing in `family` and therefore the same results (but the `call` will be different).